# Dimension of polynomials on $d$ variables with total degree less than $m$

Tags: combinatorics, functional-analysis, solution-verification

As the title suggests, I have been trying to compute the dimension of the space of polynomials on $d$ variables, say, $x_1, \ldots, x_d$, with total degree less than $m$. I thought about doing this for each $0 \leq j \leq m$ and adding these numbers. Now, for each $0 \leq j \leq m$ it would seem to me that this essentially boils down to a stars and bars problem and therefore the number of ways to have a polynomial of total degree $j$ on $x_1, \ldots, x_d$, is
$$ \binom{d+j-1}{d-1}. $$
Adding all these numbers now leads to
$$\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{d+j-1}{d-1} = \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{j+d-1}{j} .$$
I am wondering if this reasoning leads to the correct result. Thank you.

Comment: presumably your coefficients are restricted to (say) $0,1$?

Comment: @kodlu I should have been more clear; I am looking for the dimension of the space of these polynomials. In other words, the number of basis functions one would need to describe it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct—but you can say more, since
$$
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{d+j-1}{d-1} = \binom{d+m}d.
$$
And indeed you can extend the original sticks and stones argument to get this answer directly! Just add one more stick, and interpret the extra group of stones you get as "potential but wasted" exponent, which means that the resulting monomial has total degree at most $m$ rather than exactly $m$; alternatively, assign a new variable $y$ to have exponent corresponding to that extra group, and then set $y=1$ at the end (every monomial in $x_1,\dots,x_d$ of total degree at most $m$ can be uniquely extended to a monomial in $x_1,\dots,x_d,y$ of total degree exactly $m$ by multiplying by a power of $y$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think it should be $\binom{d+m}{d}$. May I ask how this equality can be derived?

Comment: Typo fixed, thanks. As for the derivation: draw Pascal's triangle and circle $\binom33$, $\binom43$, $\binom53$, $\binom63$, and $\binom73$. Can you convince yourself that the sum of those five numbers is $\binom84$? (Hint: $\binom33=\binom44$.) The general proof is just that idea written in symbols.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really neat!